# solve equation with R

Tags: numerical-methods

I want to solve the equation with R:
$$\frac{c_1^{n_1+1}}{[(n_2-1)+(n_1-1)c_1]^{n_1+n_2-2}}=\frac{c_2^{n_1+1}}{[(n_2-1)+(n_1-1)c_1]^{n_1+n_2-2}};$$
$$[F(c_2;n_1-1,n_2-1)]-[F(c_2;n_1-1,n_2-1)]=1-\alpha.$$

I want to solve out the numerical of $(c_1,c_2)$.

My attempt:

$\alpha=0.05$

$n_1=18$

$n_2=13$

$((c1^{n_1+1}))/(((n_2-1)+(n_1-1)\times c_1)^{n_1+n_2-2})=(c_2^{n_1+1})/((n_2-1)+(n_1-1)\times c_2)^{n_1+n_2-2}$

$qf(c_2,n_1-1,n_2-1)-qf(c_1,n_1-1,n_2-1)=1-\alpha$

$c(c_1,c_2)$

But it seem that something was wrong. Can anybody help me solve out this equation? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This is better asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: sorry to disturb. I will close it..

Comment: Could it be that the terms in the first equation are monotonous making $c_1=c_2$ the only solutions which makes the second equation impossible to solve as the left side is always zero.